# Set fake directory with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a directory called `/admin` - the most predictable name for an admin panel. As of right now I have created a fake directory called `/ase` using htaccess. When you go to the url, you have to log in to the admin panel. When you're not logged in to `/ase`, and you visit `/admin`, it will say 404 not found.

My htaccess is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ase admin/allseeingeye/
```

But people can still visit `admin/allseeingeye/` to log in which is located on `/admin`. Is there a PHP script like:

```
if (url = admin/allseeingeye/) {
    error 404 script
} else {
    // rest of the page
}
```

But so the page still functions on `/ase`?

The script above is completely wrong but that's just to explain.

Comment: I don't get it, so your users have to visit `www.example.com/ase` in order to log in and then they are redirected to `www.example.com/admin` and are allowed to see the inner pages? Why not put the contents of `admin` into `ase` and just tell your users that this is the new URL. I assume you have "admin" hardcoded in some of your URLs though; for that I recommend a global search for "admin" and replace with "ase" as needed.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Most/all my systems are connected to the website and the website is connected to them - when I place my `/admin` files to `/ase` the errors will be all over the place. I don't mind using `/admin` but I do mind the bruteforce attacks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a PHP script for this, you can do so in `mod_rewrite` itself using a separate rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

# forbid direct request to allseeingeye
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /allseeingeye/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

RewriteRule ^ase/?$ admin/allseeingeye/ [L,NC]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. I have tried what you suggested but I can still reach `admin/allseeingeye/`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107261/discussion-between-anubhava-and-bobby-j).